# PHP accessing private static variables vs private variables?

Tags: php, oop

This may come out like a silly question, but until right now I notice the following.

```
<?php
    class Something {
        private $another;
        private static $yetAnother;

        public function printSomething($what_to_print){
            $this->another = $what_to_print;
            $this::$yetAnother = $what_to_print;
            //print($this::$yetAnother);//prints good
            //print($this->another); //prints good
            //print($this->$another); //PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:
            //print($this::yetAnother); //PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant
        }

    }

    $x = new Something();
    $x->printSomething("Hello World!");
?>
```

Why can I access the static variable using `$` but if I don't use the system understand it as it is a const.. But I fail to understand it properly. Is just for syntax? Or is there other reason for it?

Comment: `$this->$another` will be evaluted by PHP to a dynamic var. When running this code PHP is trying to access `$this->Hello World`, which is a property that is non-existant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are class properties, not object properties. So they are shared for all objects with the same value and they are available without having an object at all. So the correct way to access these properties would be from inside the class by self::$yetAnother (or static::$yetAnother) or Something::$yetAnother from outside, if public. "$this->" is a reference on the object but the property $yetAnother is not an object property but static class property so you can access the property by that way (php is not very restrictive here) but the correct way was self::, static:: or classname::.

Since a variable needs a $ as prefix that's why you cannot access it by $this::yetAnother or self::yetAnother because this would be name of a const. That's why $this::yetAnother is giving you an error since there is no const by that name.